# Gathering Accelerometer data in background

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer

I'm writing an app, that has to do some calculations every time the phone moves. I've read every question here, but couldn't get the Accelerometer to gather data in the background (after the user navigates away from the app). I've set the `Location updates` flag in the `Plist.info`. This is the code I'm using:

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

func startMotionUpdates() {
    var timestamps = [NSDate]()

    if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue(), withHandler: { (data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let time = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: data!.timestamp)
                timestamps.append(time)
                print(timestamps)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I tried every combination out there, I've tried using `CMDeviceMotion`, I've tried using `CLLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` to simulate background activity, but nothing works. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be woken up every time the accelerometer changes. You can be woken up whenever the location of the device changes significantly (at least several meters) using `CLLocationManager`, and that's what "location" means in the background modes.

To track finer-grained motion information, you need to ask the system to start recording the data using `CMSensorRecorder`, and then later you can ask for the data and compute what you want from it. But you won't be allowed to run in the background continuously watching every jiggle of the device. That would eat too much battery.

See also `CMPedometer` which addresses certain use cases more directly.

Comment: I need to know every time the user has changed his location or has started moving. You say I will be woken up, when the location has changed with several meters, but the documentation for `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` states, that it's actually 500 or more, which doesn't work for me. Is there any other way to do this?